# Faster insert sqlite3 processing

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sqlite

I have this function where it opens a .TXT file with some products and insert line by line on the sqlitedb. The process is working fine, the problem is. This file contains 2000+ lines, because of that, the process is taking several hours to finish. I wonder if there is a way to make the process a little bit faster.

here is the function:

```
   private void carrega_produtos()
    {
        var assembly = typeof(sincroniza_page).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            if (res.Contains("produtos.txt"))
            {
                Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(res);
                var st = res.Count();
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string linha;
                    acesso_banco_produtos banco = new acesso_banco_produtos();
                    while ((linha = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        List<string> lista = linha.Split(new char[] { '§' }).ToList();
                        var cod = int.Parse(lista.ElementAt(0));
                        var nome_prod = lista.ElementAt(1);
                        var cod_grupo = lista.ElementAt(2);
                        var nm_grupo = lista.ElementAt(3);
                        var ind_ativo = lista.ElementAt(4);
                        var val_custo_unit = lista.ElementAt(5);
                        var val_custo = lista.ElementAt(6);
                        var perc_imposto = lista.ElementAt(7);
                        var unidade_med = lista.ElementAt(8);
                        var qtd_mes_1 = lista.ElementAt(9);
                        var qtd_mes_2 = lista.ElementAt(10);
                        var qtd_mes_3 = lista.ElementAt(11);
                        var qtd_mes_6 = lista.ElementAt(12);
                        var qtd_mes_12 = lista.ElementAt(13);
                        var data = lista.ElementAt(14);

                        var bd = new banco_produtos()
                        {
                            cod_produto = cod,
                            nm_produto = nome_prod,
                            cod_grupo = cod_grupo,
                            nm_grupo = nm_grupo,
                            ind_ativo = ind_ativo,
                            val_custo_unitario = Double.Parse(val_custo_unit),
                            val_lista_preco = val_custo,
                            perc_impostos = perc_imposto,
                            unidade_medida = unidade_med,
                            qtde_vendida_mes_1 = qtd_mes_1,
                            qtde_vendida_mes_2 = qtd_mes_2,
                            qtde_vendida_mes_3 = qtd_mes_3,
                            qtde_vendida_mes_6 = qtd_mes_6,
                            qtde_vendida_mes_12 = qtd_mes_12

                        };
                         //here i look in the DB if already exists the new product
                        var procura = banco.get_produto(cod);

                        if (procura == null)
                        {
                           // here is inserted to the db
                            banco.inserir_produto(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    valor += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you profiled it, which part of the code was slow?

Comment: It will not change anything substantial, but when you get the _cod_ just check immediately the database. You can avoid to extract the data and the preparation of the object.

Comment: @mjwills, When I did the insert into the db, some android versions would take 2~3 seconds to insert.

Comment: Which specific line is taking 2-3 seconds?

Comment: Is there an index affecting inserts that you can drop then recreate after?

Comment: Which sqlite3 library are you using? I've faced kind of similar issue some time ago, maybe my solution works for you.

Comment: @mjwills, when I do the checking on the DB if already exists or not the new product `var procura = banco.get_produto(cod);`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is inside your method which inserts data into db but the most common issue with SQLite and massive inserts is the fact that SQLite by default wraps every insert with transaction which creates significant overhead. A good practice for such cases is to make signle transaction for all insterts which should singificantly improve the perfomance, see the [example](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/make-your-sqlite-bulk-inserts-very-fast-in-c/).

Comment: Now with further tests I've seen that what takes time is when I search on the DB with the product already exists. The insert is not taking any time to do it.

Comment: You can deal with it in couple of ways. For example you can use unique constraint for the `cod_produto` column and just filter out the unique constraint exception or you can use WHERE NOT EXISTS technique in the SQL INSERT statement which will allow you not to retrieve a product information to the application.

Answer (score 0):

I did what @Dmytro said, I used the method "insertORIgnore". It improved a lot using that method.thank you for the help.